# Question about the pamameters of Arcto in sverchok's "Profile Parametric Node"

Tags: add-on, sverchok

```
<2v rx,ry> <float rot> <int flag1> <int flag2> <2v x,y> <int num_verts> [z]
```

As the syntax above shows，**[ArcTo](http://nikitron.cc.ua/sverch/html/nodes/generator/profile_parametric.html)** has 3 parameters（ *float rot*, *int flag1* and *int flag2* ） between the radius vector and the coordinate vecter.  
I've found that the third(*int flag2*) can be used to set the direction of the arc(CW or CCW),but I can't find out what the other 2 parameters( *float rot* and *int flag1* ) stand for and can be used to do.  
It will be kind of you to tell me the answer, and thanks in advance.^_^

Comment: We (team sverchok) encourage you to use the github issue tracker to tell us which parts of our documentation are unclear. We try to cover everything but sometimes might gloss over some details like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This node was intended to closely resemble the SVG style of specifying paths, and you should really look at what SVG specs say about ArcTo

```lisp
;; straight from the svg specs
(rx ry x-axis-rotation large-arc-flag sweep-flag x y)
```

For a deeper description see this github issue tracker post:
https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/issues/350#issuecomment-51353886

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer and tip.
Maybe be I should read more issue tracker posts.